# My function in my controller works but does not update the view (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, view, controller

I've some fields, they can be edited. The user can cancel the edition mode with the button 'Cancel':

```
<button ng-click="cancelEdit();" ng-show="editable">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel
</button>
```

The event ng-click call the function `cancelEdit()`.

```
$scope.cancelEdit = function(){
    $scope.editable=false;
    $scope.jobNameInput = $scope.jobToView.name;
    $scope.selectedPriority = $scope.jobToView.priority;
    $scope.jobCommentsInput = $scope.jobToView.comments;
}
```

In this function, I just want to set the boolean variable for edition mode to false and reinit the values of my inputs to the default value (before edition mode). After this function is calling, the values are updated for the controller, but not in my view:

```
<button ng-click="editable=true;" ng-show="!editable">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</button>
```

This button is shown when the variable editable is set to false. So when I click on the cancel button, theoretically, the button Edit must be shown and my inputs should be updated. Why is this not the case ?

Comment: Could you show how are you binding `$scope.jobNameInput` and the other values in the view? What's the vaue of $scope.jobToView.name? If you could make a snipped or a plnkr, that would be great. So we can assist you better.

Comment: mmm try so set  ng-click="editable=true;"  not in the button but with a function .. so  ng-click="setEditTrue()" and then $scope.setEditTrue= function(){ $scope.editable=true; }

Comment: Try to replace the editable variable to a property of an object, not as a property of the $scope, something like: buttonEditable = {value:true}; Then in your htlml: ng-click="buttonEditable.value=true"

Comment: When I tried to do the plunker, it worked. I think that it is a problem related to the fact that I display these inputs only if the user clicks on a button before using a ng-class (checked / !checked).

An example of input:

`<input type="text" ng-model="jobCommentsInput" ng-value="jobToView.comments" ng-disabled="!editable" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primitives are immutable** – i.e. its value cannot be changed by invoking functions on it.

Your `$scope.editable` is a `boolean` variable which is primitive. That's why the view does not get updated. Its value gets changed only in the closure of your function.

To apply it in your view you should **change it to a non primitive value**. This could be done if you set it as a property of an object.

E.g.

```
$scope.isEditable = {
  value:false
}
```

Then play around with that object. In your case:

Cancel button:

```
<button ng-click="cancelEdit();" ng-show="isEditable.value">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel
</button>
```

Edit button:

```
<button ng-click="isEditable.value=true;" ng-show="!isEditable.value">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</button>
```

Function:

```
$scope.cancelEdit = function(){
    $scope.isEditable.value = false;
    $scope.jobNameInput = $scope.jobToView.name;
    $scope.selectedPriority = $scope.jobToView.priority;
    $scope.jobCommentsInput = $scope.jobToView.comments;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know that the primitive types were not updatable. And in terms of input, do you have any idea? Because, in this case, I use the jobToView object.

Comment: You could follow the same strategy. e.g. `job = {name:"", priority:"", comments:""}`. Then use this object properties in the view.

Comment: I already use my jobToView object in my view. But when I step through my cancelEdit function, the value of my input is already equal to my default value. As if he does not see the changes I made the time they were edited. While having the display, after having passed my function, it keeps the modifications that I made.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Korte for the answer on the boolean variable. 
To complete, with regard to the inputs, I found the answer to my question. Simply declare in the controller:`var vm = this;`;

And simply, in the model of the input, write: `ng-model="vm.jobCommentsInput"`

I think so the inputs are considered as my boolean variable and they needs to be objects.